How do I create this kind of delayed scroll when there are two columns with different heights?
Here's the reference:
https://www.sennheiser.com/en-us/catalog/products/microphones/mk-4/mk-4-504298
I'm sure it can be done with pure CSS, but I don't know how to approach it.
It's a very effective way to represent a product or to manage empty space next to a photo. I could see it more often.

Please describe your question in the post itself rather than posting a link, a link might be dead in the future and no one will be able to understand the question causing the question to be useless.

If you're talking about the vertical scrolling, it can be done easily using position:sticky
